# Hide a specific list from 'View All Site Content' using JSOM/CSOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom, ajax, jsom

I see you can make a list hidden by using SharePoint Designer (http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/how-to-hide-list-or-library-in-sharepoint.html) which I am not interested in.

It is okay if the list is available via the URL.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the list from specific people or everyone? If it's specific people, why not just remove permissions for those people from the list. Then they won't be able to see it on "All site content" view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
list.Hidden = true;
list.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Source: [Hide document library using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115058/hide-document-library-using-csom)

Note that in the source they use BreakRoleInheritance to prevent users from accessing the list.

Comment: I don't think your code will do anything, as the default value for `Hidden` should be `false`. But using `true` will hide the list (while still letting it be accessible with a direct link).

Comment: The question has a number of javascript tags, this answer is for the C# CSOM instead of the JavaScript JSOM - the answers will certainly be similar but not the same (there is no `ExecuteQuery` in JSOM)

Comment: Correct you can see Matt answer in JS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everybody's responses. Close to jpussacq's question I was able to get it working by using the lists hidden attribute by using the set_hidden(true) in the following way:

```
//JSOM example
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(hideListItem, "sp.js");

  function hideListItem(){ 
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext().get_current();

  var thisList  = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My List');

  thisList.set_hidden(true);
  //must be updated before loading
  thisList.update();

  ctx.load(thisList);

  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){



  });

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call `ctx.load`.

Comment: And remember that the content in lists with hidden = true will not be crawled